# Regex Select [A-Z ] except two consecutive spaces

Tags: c#, regex, string

I've been trying to create a regex to match all letters from A-Z and a single space. I want it to stop when it becomes more than 1 consecutive space. I also do not want the dash included. This is being called and returned as a string in a C# based program. I plan to just crop the string at the end by 1 after I have imported it to remove the space at the end (if it ends up being returned by regex).

```
TERRA MARVELLOUS LUX      -
```

So far I've tried a multitude of expressions the best I can come up with so far is

```
^[A-Z (?!\s{2,})]*
```

as well as

```
^[A-Z ]*(?:\s{2})
```

and so on I could list more I've been trying. I'm quite stuck.

Comment: Do you just want to remove final whitespace and hyphens if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[A-Z ]+\b
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/20

Comment: Its not really helping case you have "more than one    string divided   with two spaces   on one line  " but  I don't know whether it is possible to have it, its not clear from question.

Comment: This regex matches `TERRA MARVELLOUS  LUX` (double spaces removed in comments) with double spaces between "MARVELLOUS" and "LUX". Acc. to the OP, when consecutive spaces appear, the match should not include what follows.

Comment: I don't believe it will happen, if it does I'll likely rewrite it. But for the time being this works wonderfully. And thank you for the site. I was using  http://regexpal.com/ This is far better.

Comment: @stribizhev m not very sure of what OP wants.If he clairifes that can be done

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your issue:

```
([A-Z]+[ ]{1})+
```

The main idea is to match all the groups of at least one character of A-Z, then have one space and match the pattern at least one time.

And the example:
https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/21

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just strip final spaces with hyphen, you can use

```
 var t1 = "TERRA MARVELLOUS  LUX      -";
 var rx2 = new Regex(@"\s+\-?$");
 var res = rx2.Replace(t1, string.Empty);
```